# A couple of questions on building the development and release git branches in the same Jenkins project?

Tags: github, jenkins, msbuild

We have git branches named as "development", "release*" and "feature*". They are .net application so it's using the Jenkins MSBuild plugin as shown in the screenshot below. The only differences from a development build and a release build are the commandline arguments and some extra steps in release build to upload to Nexus, etc.

Now we always have two Jenkins projects for each application, app1_dev and app1_rel, probably we need to create another one for hotfix. I am looking at the possibility to merge them together into one project. 
1. Use an inverse strategy and branch spefcifier as "feature*", the project will build the master, development, release*, hotfix*, etc.
2. Use conditional step to exclude steps only for release build, based on the branch name. How to do this?
3. Use condition and parameters to change the MSBuild commandline arguments based on the branch name. How to do this?
4. Anything else?

Comment: I figured I can get the branch name from %GIT_BRANCH%. It shows like origin/master. Now how can I create a conditional step based on this variable. I find no proper condition to use in the Conditional step. The easiest way for me is using a regexp here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one called [Multi-Branch Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin)

Comment: I quickly tried. It creates a new project for each branch. This is almost the opposite from what I want. I want to have one single project to build all branches.